# Cannot access /wp-admin because of fatal error in post.php

Tags: php, wordpress

After updating some of my plugins, it seems that I am not able to access /wp-admin. It answers with the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare redirect_post() (previously declared in /wp-admin/includes/post.php:1856) in /wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 1856

By accessing FTP I found the following line, however I do not know what to do from here.

```
function redirect_post($post_id = '') {
```

Comment: `Cannot redeclare redirect_post()` means you have tow declaration of redirect_post, remove one of them and try again :)

Comment: Seems like you, somehow, are including the same file twice. @MacBooc - It looks like both paths lead to the same file and line.

Comment: Seem some plugins include file twice.

Comment: Try and disable all your plugins and enable them one by one to find out if any of the plugins are doing something strange.

Comment: hmm can't edit my first but yeah, i read too fast. Indeed included the file twice. I wonder why they do not use `include_once` into plugins

Comment: Thanks for all the solutions. It seems that removing all the content from the folder helped. So I downloaded it before doing this in case something happens in the future. Thanks so much for the help guys!